# How to complete a Search in NetSuite using Java API?

Tags: java, perl, web-services, netsuite

I have a jar file nsws-2014_1.jar with the bindings for using Netsuite's web services.  I am reading through their examples in the pdf which they have provide online, but the search or querying is confusing.  I would like to complete a query that someone has done in perl, but in java. Can someone help me out?

```
my $query = {
    basic => [
        { name => 'customFieldList', value => [
                {
                    name => 'customField',
                    attr => {
                        scriptId => 'custentity_hexid',
                        operator => 'is',
                        'xsi:type' =>         'core_2013_2.platform:SearchStringCustomField'
                    },
                    value => $json->{'ServiceOrder'}->{'Id'}
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

Comment: how do you download 'nsws-2014_1.jar ' from ?

Comment: 2014 is out of date. You need use Javaee tool to create java axis bindings for 2019 if you want current. You need access to netsuite’s help section to see their article on how to do this because it isn’t straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  CustomerSearch customerSrch = new CustomerSearch();
  CustomerSearchBasic customerSrchBsc = new CustomerSearchBasic();

  SearchStringCustomField custentity_externalid =  new SearchStringCustomField();
  custentity_externalid.setInternalId("1015");
  custentity_externalid.setSearchValue(externalID);
  custentity_externalid.setOperator(SearchStringFieldOperator.is);

  SearchCustomFieldList searchCustomFieldList = new SearchCustomFieldList();
  SearchCustomField[] SearchCustomFieldArray = {custentity_externalid};
  searchCustomFieldList.setCustomField(SearchCustomFieldArray);
  customerSrchBsc.setCustomFieldList(searchCustomFieldList);
  customerSrch.setBasic(customerSrchBsc);


  SearchResult searchResult = _service.search(customerSrch);
```